# How to improve computational time by parallelizing

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I have written a c++ code (using STL) and due to large computations it takes about one hour for the output to come. I checked on parallelizing on GPU and CPU. I have a ATI graphics card and a core i7 processor. On which one should i parallelize for better results.
Also can you please suggest reading material on how to set up my compiler for parallelizing on any of these platforms and how do i start parallelizing

Comment: The best way to start is google it. What have you found out?

Comment: Too generic. No enough informations. Your question cannot have an answer. However not everything can be parallelized with success in multiprocessor machines and\or in GPU. For GPU the problem is more complicated since GPU can be used to parallelize just some type of mathematical or algebraic computation but GPUs were not created for this reason, they were created for games.

Comment: Way too broad. At the very least inform us what you're trying to parallelize so we at least get a clue of the nature of the problem.

Comment: Indeed. as others are saying, it is one of those areas that it really depends on what you are trying to compute, so that kind of details cannot really be avoided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general libraries regarding multi-core/GPU programming:

- [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) for GPU/CPU STL-like interface programming
- [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) for multi-threaded parallel code
- [TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) Intel Threading Building Blocks, lots of primitive data structures for parallel programming

in general, this area is absolutely vast, and no answer can make justice of the topic. There are many ways to approach parallelization, and that begins with analysing your logic and looking in parts that can be efficiently computed in parallel, and design (or redesign) your algorithms around those results.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider recoding your numerical kernels using [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) (and its ATI Stream implementation for your graphical card).

Comment: And parallelizing numerical code is difficult (impossible) to do automatically and generally. You'll have to recode or annotate things.  See also http://opengpu.net/EN/